# linq - condtionally hide a property in a .select() statement

Tags: linq

[frangment of a linq query]

```
query.Select(c => new OdsSummaryResponse
                {
                    Id = c.RISODS_Id,
                    Driver = c.CDGOREC.Where(a => a.CDGOREC_Conducente).FirstOrDefault().PERSONALE.PERSONE.PERSONE_CognomeNome,
                    Operators = c.CDGOREC.Where(a => myexternavar == true && !a.CDGOREC_Conducente && a.CDGOREC_PersonaleId != null).Select( d => new Operatori() {   
                        Id = (int)d.CDGOREC_PersonaleId,
                        Nominativo = d.PERSONALE.PERSONE.PERSONE_CognomeNome,
                        Codice = d.PERSONALE.PERSONALE_Codice
                    }).ToList()
               }).OrderByDescending(c => Id);
```

in the subquery `Operators = c.CDGOREC.Where`  when an external variable `myexternavar=false` i'd like to completely hide the property "Operators" from the output.
But this code shows me an empty array,

```
{
    "Id": 194214,
    "Driver": "XXXXXXXX",
    "OperatorsNo": 1,
    "Operators": []    //i'd like to hide this property if myexternavar=false
  }
```

is it possible to exclude the property at all???

Comment: How is your JSON being generated? Are you using Json.Net?

Comment: @haim770 yes Json.Net, the json is above

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Conditional Property Serialization](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConditionalProperties.htm) to instruct the Serializer when to include that property.

For example, the following will not emit the `Operators` property when it's either `null` or empty:

```
public class OdsSummaryResponse
{
    // ...

    public IList<Operatori> Operators { get; set;}

    public bool ShouldSerializeOperators()
    {
        return this.Operators?.Count > 0;
    }
}
```